# Spring 4, JSON - HTTP Error 406 Not Acceptable

Tags: java, json, spring, maven, model-view-controller

I've created controller for fullCalendar eventSource, unfortunatelly something went wrong and every time I try to open this page I got HTTP ERROR 406.

My Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/schedule", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Object getEventyJSON(Principal principal){
    String name = principal.getName();
    List<Eventy> eventy = userService.findOneWithEventy(name).getEventy();

    List<HashMap<String,String>> events = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < eventy.size(); i++) {
        HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
        map.put("title", eventy.get(i).getTitle());
        map.put("start", eventy.get(i).getStart());
        events.add(map);
    }

    return events;
}
```

My POM.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Of course I've tried to change dependency to codehaus instead of fasterxml and it's not working. Also I've tried to add some headers to method.

When i change controller to this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/schedule", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody Object getEventyJSON(Principal principal){
        String name = principal.getName();
        List<Eventy> eventy = userService.findOneWithEventy(name).getEventy();


        return "schedule";
    }
```

It is working and when I open that page it print schedule so it is correct.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

406 happens when the server(your back end) cannot respond with the Accept-Type HTTP header specified in the request. So basically your server is returning different response type that is in the Client requests Accept-Header.

> The resource identified by the request is only capable of generating response entities which have content characteristics not acceptable according to the accept headers sent in the request.

check [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

Answer (score 0):

In the call you are making to the resource you need to tell it what content type you are expecting

If you are using JQuery something like this would work

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/schedule",
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType : "json",
    success: function (d) {
        // do something with the json
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm using FullCalendar 1.4 or 1.6 and I've got this:  events: '/schedule', It should work. I've changed it the way you have and still http error 406

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/schedule", produces= "application/json")
public @ResponseBody List<Eventy> getEventy(Principal principal){
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your method to return a String and, within your method, transform your list into a JSON String. For that, you could use google-gson but, given that we're playing with spring already and probably already have those dependencies in the project, you can use Jackson's ObjectMapper. like this:

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/schedule", method = RequestMethod.GET,headers="Accept=*/*",produces = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody String getEventyJSON(Principal principal) throws JsonProcessingException {
        // NOTE1: change the method to return a "String"
        // NOTE2: add "throws JsonProcessingException" to the method (or catch it)
    String name = principal.getName();
    List<Eventy> eventy = userService.findOneWithEventy(name).getEventy();
    List<HashMap<String,String>> events = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < eventy.size(); i++) {
        HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
        map.put("title", eventy.get(i).getTitle());
        map.put("start", eventy.get(i).getStart());
        events.add(map);
    }
    //return events;
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    return mapper.writeValueAsString(events);
}
```

Also add these 2 imports:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
```

I'm pretty sure the above will fix it for you. But there is one more thing to try if the above doesn't fix your 406 error response, add this to the @RequestMapping:

```
headers="Accept=*/*",produces = "application/json"
```

ex:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/schedule", method = RequestMethod.GET,headers="Accept=*/*",produces = "application/json")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your method to return a String and, within your method, transform your list into a JSON String. For that, you could use google-gson but, given that we're playing with spring already and probably already have those dependencies in the project, you can use Jackson's ObjectMapper. like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/schedule", method = RequestMethod.GET,headers="Accept=*/*",produces = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody String getEventyJSON(Principal principal) throws JsonProcessingException {
    // NOTE1: change the method to return a "String"
    // NOTE2: add "throws JsonProcessingException" to the method (or catch it)
    String name = principal.getName();
    List<Eventy> eventy = userService.findOneWithEventy(name).getEventy();
    List<HashMap<String,String>> events = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < eventy.size(); i++) {
        HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
        map.put("title", eventy.get(i).getTitle());
        map.put("start", eventy.get(i).getStart());
        events.add(map);
    }
    //return events;
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    return mapper.writeValueAsString(events);
}
```

Also add these 2 imports:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
```

I'm pretty sure the above will fix it for you. But there is one more thing to try if the above doesn't fix your 406 error response, add this to the @RequestMapping:

```
headers="Accept=*/*",produces = "application/json"
```

Ex:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/schedule", method = RequestMethod.GET,headers="Accept=*/*",produces = "application/js
```

Answer (score 0):

You need this in your request mapping

```
@RequestMapping(value="/schedule", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/json")
```

You may also need these dependencies

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a dependency missing in your pom.xml

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
```